# How to generate tweets in python using twitter api?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tweets

I have the necessary imports and Twitter API credentials

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

#Define Twitter handle and API endpoint

```
handle = "CommBank"
url = f"https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=from:{handle}&tweet.fields=created_at&expansions=author_id&user.fields=created_at"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {BEARER_TOKEN}"}
```

```
tweet_count = 100
params = {"max_results": tweet_count}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

```
if response.status_code == 200:
     tweets_data = response.json()
     for tweet in tweets_data.get("data", []):
          print(tweet.get("text"))
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My current code does not generate any tweets. Because this is my first time using API generation, it might be a conceptual difficulty.